# Retriving certain amount of rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"X1": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "B","C","C","C"],
"X2": ['FOO','BAR' ,'FOO1', 'BAR1', 'FOO2','BAR2','FOO3','BAR3']})

    X1  X2
0   A   FOO
1   B   BAR
2   A   FOO1
3   B   BAR1
4   B   FOO2
5   C   BAR2
6   C   FOO3
7   C   BAR3
```

Now I am doing the value counts which give A:2, B:3, C:3, and I want to extract the rows according to counts of A. So that, I can have a dataframe in which 2 rows of A, 2 rows of B and 2 rows of C.

So output should be,

```
    X1  X2
0   A   FOO
2   A   FOO1
1   B   BAR
3   B   BAR1
5   C   BAR2
6   C   FOO3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html) with count `A` values by `sum` compared values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==` with sorting by column `X1`:

```
N = df['X1'].eq('A').sum()
df = df.sort_values('X1').groupby('X1').head(N)
print (df)
  X1    X2
0  A   FOO
2  A  FOO1
1  B   BAR
3  B  BAR1
5  C  BAR2
6  C  FOO3
```